# Unable to produce output (log or PDF file) using latexmk (MikTeX, Windows 10)

Tags: latexmk

I've run into a problem today with (I think) `latexmk`. I'm unable to get `latekmk` to produce any output when I try to build a TeX document. In particular, trying to run `latexmk` in PowerShell to build a PDF for my `test.tex` file produces the following in PowerShell (but no log/aux file or PDF are produced in the directory).

```
PS C:\Users\username\Desktop> latexmk.exe -pdf .\test.tex
Rc files read:
  NONE
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 29 May 2021, version: 4.74b.
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      './test.tex'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex  -recorder  ".\test.tex"'
------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (MiKTeX 21.8)
entering extended mode
(test.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-08-27>
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/standalone\standalo
ne.cls
Document Class: standalone 2018/03/26 v1.3a Class to compile TeX sub-files stan
dalone
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\shellesc.sty)

(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\ifluatex.st
y (C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty
))
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xkeyval\xkeyval.sty

(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkeyval.t
ex
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkvutils.
tex
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\keyval.te
x))))
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/standalone\standalo
ne.cfg)
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo)))
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend
-pdftex.def) (test.aux) [1{C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/pdftex/confi
g/pdftex.map}] (test.aux) )<C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fo
nts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 10895 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
Latexmk: Examining 'test.log'
=== TeX engine is 'pdfTeX'
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'test.pdf'
Latexmk: All targets (test.pdf) are up-to-date
```

If I run `pdflatex -recorder test.tex` in PowerShell, I get the following output in PowerShell:

```
PS C:\Users\username\Desktop> pdflatex -recorder .\test.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (MiKTeX 21.8)
entering extended mode
(test.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-08-27>
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/standalone\standalo
ne.cls
Document Class: standalone 2018/03/26 v1.3a Class to compile TeX sub-files stan
dalone
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\shellesc.sty)

(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\ifluatex.st
y (C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty
))
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xkeyval\xkeyval.sty

(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkeyval.t
ex
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkvutils.
tex
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\keyval.te
x))))
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/standalone\standalo
ne.cfg)
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo)))
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend
-pdftex.def) (test.aux) [1{C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/pdftex/confi
g/pdftex.map}] (test.aux) )<C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fo
nts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 11375 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
```

However, this successfully produces the desired PDF and corresponding log/aux files.

I'm really at a loss to understand what's wrong here, and would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: both logs show a successful run and pdf file made

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at this @David. That's part of what's so confusing about this to me: I don't see any indication in the `latekmk` output in PowerShell that indicates an error occurred, but despite the message produced I can't find a .log or .pdf file in the directory with my TeX file. But I don't know if `latexmk` defaults to a different output directory.

Comment: if all else fails search for the file using the windows file search in the toolbar, it will be somewhere....

Comment: Ah, `latexmk` is outputting into `C:/VTRoot/` for some reason. I don't know why it started doing this today, but now I have a better idea of what's going on. Thanks again!

Comment: To reinforce David's point: I see from the output that no RC files were read, so latexmk is using its default configuration, with log and pdf files in the current directory.  The messages from latexmk in the last few lines of the listing, show that latexmk did actually find the files as expected.  There would be an error message if it didn't.  So something else is surely going on beyond what latexmk does.